# Can't find SqlServerManager.msc

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, windows-10, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

I Installed SQL Server Data tools (SSDT) 2016.

I want to run SQL Server Manager, but I didn't find it.

I Spent more than enough time in searching inside my system files and googling but I couldn't resolve the problem.

SqlServerManager13.msc (or any version of it e.g. - 12 / 11) does not exist in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` or `C:\Windows\Windows32` or `C:\Windows`.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a standalone product but an add-in for Visual Studio. To access it, run Visual Studio, go to the View menu and select SQL Server Object Explorer.

> The SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio offers a view of your
>   database objects similar to SQL Server Management Studio. SQL Server
>   Object Explorer allows you to do light-duty database administration
>   and design work. You can easily create, edit, rename and delete
>   tables, stored procedures, types, and functions. You can also edit
>   table data, compare schemas, or execute queries by using contextual
>   menus right from the SQL Server Object Explorer.

For a more detailed description see [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx).

YouTube tutorial here: [Using SQL Server Data Tools SSDT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPll3dMxTXU)

Comment: Thanks Dear. My problem solved by installing SQL Express. @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ